# App got rejected for missing Purpose String in Info.plist File Microphone, but I can't add the description in info.plist

Tags: ios, react-native, permissions, app-store

My app got rejected because of Missing Purpose String in `Info.plist` File (in particular for the `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` usage).

This depends on the use of `react-native-permission` usage and I've tried to add a purpose string in the `info.plist` as stated in the documentation of the module. 
But in my app I use also the `react-native-qrcode-scanner` module, and if I add the string for the `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription`, it will be asked to the user the usage of the microphone and the so the app gets rejected in the second approval process because I don't need this permission in my app.

Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

If any function of app needs to use Microphone only then app will ask user for permission. Otherwise, it won't ask it. As you only use `react-native-qrcode-scanner` user won't be asked for microphone permission. It will be just in your info.plist. I have also published app in appstore. And I have a bunch of unnecessary Purpose String in info.plist for `react-native-permission`. But it didn't cause any hamper to get approval.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Anyway if you insert in the info.plist the microphone string, react-native-qrcode-scanner will ask for the permission. Are you sure it doesn’t ask in your app?

Comment: Yes, my app also use ```react-native-qrcode-scanner ```

Comment: it will only ask if the microphone is accessed by your app. Is there anything or any feature of your app need microphone

Comment: Ok, then you don't have to worry

Comment: Yes, but if I insert the plist info for the microphone, it prompts me the request to use the microphone although I don't use any component that actually use it.

You can check the permissions behaviour here: https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192856/discussion-between-masuk-helal-anik-and-xcsob).